# jquery $.get empty data after execution

Tags: php, jquery

I have a php array containing 3 values. On a foreach base I execute the following code:

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
        <?php foreach($messaggi as $messaggio){  ?>
            $.get("scrollrtl.php", function(data){
                $('.messaggi').after(data);           
            });
        <?php } ?>
     });
</script>
```

scrollrtl.php now just echoes 'Hello World'. The result is that first time 'Hello World' is echoed once, then twice and the loop ends with seven times 'Hello World' on the page instead of three. I think it is because i don't reset data after each $get but I don't know how to do it.

Any help?

EDIT:
**scrollrtl.php:**

```
<div  id="scroll_left" class="messaggi jscroller_horz"> 
    <ul> 
    <li id="messaggio">This is the text 1</li> 
    </ul> 
</div>
```

**array results:**

```
Array ( [id] => 1
        [nome] => Prova di messaggio che scorre
        [testo] => Questo è un messaggio che scorre ...
        [template] => scrollrtl ) 
Array ( [id] => 3
        [nome] => ci ritento
        [testo] => vediamo se questa volta la cosa...
        [template] => scrollrtl ) 
Array ( [id] => 6
        [nome] => MESSAGGIO
        [testo] => Messaggio
        [template] => scrollrtl )
```

Tried the code step by step and I see that the first time is echoed once and then duplicated...

Comment: Did you know that you can use PHP to print into a JavaScript array? Put the values of $messaggi into a var array below the $(document) line.  Then iterate over it's values with javascript ‘for' ? Cleaner and simpler.

Comment: Yes I know but actually the real code is a bit more complex and I need to iterate through this code structure.

Comment: I tried your code with a very simple PHP array `array('small','medium',large')` and it only printed three times. p.s. It would help for viewing if the array was formatted.

Comment: Are all of your 'array results' the $messaggi array, with $messaggio 'id' values of 1, 3 & 6 ?

Comment: Unless you have some other code affecting $messaggi, I don't see how to get your results from the code above. Remember that $messaggio _appears to be_ an array also.

Comment: Yes, this is all I have in the array. It is fetched from a mysql db through PDO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!. It was necessary to add last() to the javascript code. After() insert data following EACH matching element and so duplicates the rows.

```
$('.messaggi').after(data);
```

becomes

```
$('.messaggi').last().after(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not related to the "data" variable in javascript, since that one is local for each function call (because its defined as parameter of the function). The javascript you posted works as you expect it.

Therefore the way I see it, there are 2 possible causes:

1. The scrollrtl.php file returns something else than you expected.
2. The $messaggi array contains more than 3 entries.

Could you post source code for scrollrtl.php file and var_dump output of the $messsaggi (var_dump($messaggi) variable before it enters the foreach loop?

Comment: I have edited the question to add scrollrtl.php (that at the moment is just html) and print_r($messaggi) to show you what is inside the loop. Placing an alert(id) on each foreach i see that the code runs three times but duplicates the results each time: first time one, second time two and third time four. So one + two + three is seven...